# How automatically to copy contents?

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose in MS Excel, I write `100` in a cell (say cell A) positioned in sheet1, column 1, row 5 then how can I copy the same data to another cell (say cell B) positioned in another sheet of the same Excel file, say to sheet2 , column 5, row 2.

So if I change value of cell A, then the value  of cell B should automatically change to the new value of cell A.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly (seems way too basic for a programmer's help community). Try referencing cell A in cell B:

```
=sheet1!A5
```

Just put the = in cell b, then click on the other cell, Excel puts the reference there for you.